# Does Gmail Promotions Tab Annotation impact on Inbox Delivery?

Tags: gmail, gmail-promo-tab

Recently we implemented the "Gmail Promotions Tab Annotation" for one of our customer where we could see mailer which sent through annotation landed in spam where as other emails are inbox without any issue.

We used same sender id & sender domain. Can anyone help over here ? anyone faced same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The script tag / annotation for the new Gmail promo tab features doesn't affect the Gmail Tab classifier or the spam filter. There have been issues if the links included in the annotation or any where in an email are not secure, however this is not related to the annotation directly. The team working on the redesigned promo tab features have monitored this with billions of email. Source [website](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/faq).